# Google Sheets Script, how to create a NEW loose object of a sheet tab

Tags: object, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, reference

I can't find the answer but it might be that I'm looking for the wrong things.

I got a sheet that got tabs for every letter in the alphabet and those includes data beginning
on that letter. I now want to copy those line into a summary sheet but before I just copy it
I need to remove the first line from every tab as that is the heading, the heading should not
appear over and over down all the lines in the new summary tab.

If I just do a variable of a tab and remove the first line, like:
`var sheets = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);`, this will reflect into the tab itself
and that is wrong as the heading is now gone in that tab and that I can understand as it is not
a new object but a referencing variable.

I tried to create a new object like: `var sheets = new Object(ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]));`
and then change that figuring it wouldn't touch the tab itself as this is now not a reference object
but it seems it is, as changing the 'sheets' variable still changes the original data in that tab.

I hope that makes it clear.

How can I create a new object of that tab and is NOT a reference but a COPY of it so I can do
whatever I want to that object without changing the original data in the tab it came from.

Comment: please check, this [Get sheets name and rename them](https://talentnett.com/how-to-get-sheets-name-and-rename-them-using-google-script/) might help

Comment: As far as I understand you want to create a Sheet object for each letter A-Z, to sum up, you've got 26 sheets, what's the expected result? Can you please share a Spreadsheet as example or at least an image?

Comment: @Joe Vasquez, the summary is just a list of all rows in the other for easier overview and printout.
Each rows first column has the name of a town and then some other data in the rest of the columns.

Comment: I was asking about `var sheets = new Object(ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]));` as you are trying to retrieve a sheet data I was wondering if you had several sheets on your spreadsheets, by **every letter in the alphabet** you mean columns then. If this is the case, it'd be helpful to know which kind of data you are using, as I mentioned a Spreadsheet example or just an image of your image without sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this might work:

```
function summaryAZ() {
  const sA=['A','B','C'];//etc
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sumsh=ss.getSheetByName('Summary')
  sumsh.getRange(2,1,sumsh.getLastRow()-1,sumsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();//clear everything except header row
  sA.forEach((n,i)=>{
    let sh=ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let [hA, ...data]=sh.getDataRange();
    sumsh.getRange(sumsh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this will clear the summary sheet but not the heading of it,
if so it will still add all headers for the other tabs down the lines as they have headers too and it's those headers I want to remove but just as I add them into this, not the tab-data itself.

Was thinking of keeping the tab-A headers to the a header in the summary and then by adding the other tabs removing those headers but if I do that in a variable pointing to that tab, the tab itself will get the header removed and that is not correct thus leaving those without a header for future work.

Comment: No the header goes into hA and the rest of the rows go into data. Performance is improved by the fact that in this process you don't have to get the row each time we get all of the data at one time for each tab.